# How to make a button in HTML have the value of a number?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a question to how you make a button in HTML have the value of a number? I have to make a system where I can rate something. I've made 5 buttons, and I want to make each of them have a value from 1 to 5. And then each time I click on of the buttons, I get text printed where it calculates the average of the buttons' value. Does anyone know how to help?

For now I've made one button. This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1> demo </h1>

    <input type="submit" value="rate" onclick="demo();" />
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my function in JavaScript where I try to find the average:

```
var arr = [];

function demo(){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum / arr.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
}



function pushArr() {
  var val = document.getElementById("demo").value = 1; 
  arr.push(val);
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: You could use a `data` attribute on the button with the value for example

Comment: what would that look like?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to do all the math based on the contents of `arr` and not to use the current value inside the "demo" element to perform the calculation. The following works for me; you can skip some of the repetitive HTML by creating the buttons dynamically, but I guess that's beyond the scope here.

```js
const arr = [];

function calculateAverage(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum / array.length;
}

function demo(rating) {
  arr.push(rating);
  const newValue = calculateAverage(arr);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = newValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Add 1" onclick="demo(1)" />
<input type="submit" value="Add 2" onclick="demo(2)" />
<input type="submit" value="Add 3" onclick="demo(3)" />
<input type="submit" value="Add 4" onclick="demo(4)" />
<input type="submit" value="Add 5" onclick="demo(5)" />
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to give each button a common class, so that you can bind an event listener iteratively to each of them. Then, give them a `value` attribute.

Whenever a new entry is pushed into your array, you simply invoke the function to update the average. Your logic is almost correct, it's just that these lines don't make too much sense:

```
return sum / arr.length;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
const arr = [];

function updateAverage() {
  const sum = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerText = sum / arr.length;
  
  // For debugging only
  document.getElementById('arr').innerText = JSON.stringify(arr);
  document.getElementById('sum').innerText = sum;
  document.getElementById('len').innerText = arr.length;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = +button.value;
    
    arr.push(value);
    updateAverage();
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" value="1">1</button>
<button class="btn" value="2">2</button>
<button class="btn" value="3">3</button>
<button class="btn" value="4">4</button>
<button class="btn" value="5">5</button>
<br />
Average Rating:
<p id="demo">0</p>
<br /><br/ >
For debugging:
<ul>
  <li>Array: <span id="arr"></span></li>
  <li>Sum: <span id="sum"></span></li>
  <li>Length: <span id="len"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where do you get the prev and curr from?

Comment: `prev` and `curr` are arguments for the callback in `Array.prototype.reduce`: see the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a `data-` attribute. This allows you to add attribute that are not related to the HTML itself ( like `class` is ). It's only purpose is to keep information binded to an HTML element, to be use later. In your case, every button could have an attribute `data-rating`, from 1 to 5, and you could retrieve this information when you are adding a rating to your array.

```js
var arr = [];

function demo(){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum / arr.length;
}

// this variable will save the function we will run on button click
let clickEvent =  (event) => {
  let currentlyClickedButton = event.target;
  // we are parsing to int because the getAttribute function returns a string
  var val = parseInt(currentlyClickedButton.getAttribute('data-rating'));
  // we push the current value to the array
  arr.push(val);
  // we display the value using your function demo
  // we use toFixed because we only want two digit.
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = demo().toFixed(2);
};

// we add the listener onclick to every buttons.
document.querySelectorAll('.ratingButton').forEach(button => button.onclick = clickEvent);
```

```html
<h1> demo </h1>
<button class="ratingButton" data-rating="1">1 ☆</button>
<button class="ratingButton" data-rating="2">2 ☆</button>
<button class="ratingButton" data-rating="3">3 ☆</button>
<button class="ratingButton" data-rating="4">4 ☆</button>
<button class="ratingButton" data-rating="5">5 ☆</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```